# 2 questions regarding solutions for $\sqrt{a+b} - (a-b)^2 = 0$

Tags: arithmetic

Here's two questions derived from the following question:

$\quad\begin{matrix}
\text{Is there more than one solution to the following statement?} \\
\!\sqrt{a+b} - (a-b)^2 = 0 
\end{matrix}$

$\color{Blue}{(1)\!\!:\;}$How would one (dis)prove this? I.e. In what ways could one effectively determine whether an equation has more than one solution; More specifically, this one?

$\color{Blue}{(2)\!\!:\;}$Is it possible to determine this with(out) a valid solution as a sort of reference?

Cheers!

Comment: $a=b=0$ is a solution, by inspection.

Comment: @vadim123: Yes, albeit trivial...

Comment: Another "simple" solution is $a=1, b=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for *real* solutions, then note that $a+b$ and $a-b$ are just arbitrary numbers, with $a + b \ge 0$. This is because the system
$$
\begin{cases}
u = a + b\\
v = a - b
\end{cases}
$$
has a unique solution
\begin{cases}
a = \frac{u+v}{2}\\
\\
b = \frac{u-v}{2}.
\end{cases}
In the variables $u,v$ the general solution is $u = v^{4}$, which translates to
$$
a = \frac{v^{4}+v}{2}, \qquad
b = \frac{v^{4}-v}{2},
$$
as noted by **Peter Košinár**. Note that $a+b = u = v^{4}$ is always non-negative, as requested.

If it's *integer* solutions you're looking for, you get the same solutions (for $v$ an integer), as $v$ and $v^{4}$ have the same parity.

Answer (score 0):

We can rearrange to $$a+b=(a-b)^4$$

There are hence infinitely many solutions.  For example, take $a+b=2^4=16$.  Then $a-b=2$.  We solve this to get $a=9, b=7$.  Or take $a+b=3^4=81$.  Then $a-b=3$.  We solve this to get $a=42, b=39$.

Comment: Or, even more generally, $a=\frac{k^4+k}{2}$ and $b=\frac{k^4-k}{2}$ where $k$ is any real number.